# Check for occurrence of at least one non numeric value in input string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have tried many regex but it still does not work. Please tell where I might be wrong:

1. I take input from user (expecting it will be only number).
2. `myArray = str.replace(/\s+/g,"").split("");  //remove any spaces if
   present & split each character`
3. `if(/^[0-9]/.test(myArray))
   console.log("Make sure you enter all number");
   else
   console.log("Successful");`

**Output if given following input (str) :**

- 455e5 7523 1455 -> "Make sure you enter all number"
- 4555 2375 2358 -> "Make sure you enter all number" instead of "Successful"

I have tried `/^[0-9]+/` , `/^\d+$/` , `/(^\d)*/` and many similar expression. It did not help me out.
Is it because of `split()` because i have remove it and also tried.

Comment: The code works fine without 'split()' function. I had split them into array of characters/strings which was the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\D` to match non numeric character

```
if(/\D/.test(myArray))
    console.log("Make sure you enter all number");
else
    console.log("Successful");
```

**DEMO :**

```js
function test(myArray) {
  if (/\D/.test(myArray.replace(/\s+/g,"")))
    console.log("Make sure you enter all number");
  else
    console.log("Successful");
}
```

```html
<input oninput="test(this.value)" />
```

Or you can use `[^\d\s]` for matching character except digit and space

```js
function test(myArray) {
  if (/[^\d\s]/.test(myArray))
    console.log("Make sure you enter all number");
  else
    console.log("Successful");
}
```

```html
<input oninput="test(this.value)" />
```